# change the date format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date value as below in my table.

```
2015-05-25
```

I want to convert the values as below.

```
05/25
```

How to do this? Date value is having date datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CONVERT` function to change it to `mm/dd/yy` (style 1)

And the `LEFT` function to only select `mm/dd` (integer_expression 5)

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(date, 1), 5)
FROM yourtable
```

Input:

```
2015-05-25
```

Output:

```
date
05/25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select convert(varchar(5),getdate(),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it format by using Tostring()

```
string date = YourDate.ToString("MM/dd");
```

Comment: yes, this will work in C#, if you are using it at frontend, it is more easy

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
SELECT Left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1),5) AS [MM/DD]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 (or more), I advise you using the new `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'MM/dd')
```